# Override dll class property set

Tags: c#, overriding

I'm using a thousand instances of a closed DllClass in my project.

```
public sealed class DllClass 
{
    public DllClass();
    public string DllClassProperty {get; set;}
}
```

DllClassProperty set is used a thousand of times and I need to override the value set if a parameter is set on Web.config.

I found this Interface [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-implement-property-change-notification), but I can't use it, because I don't have access to the class and I can't extend it.

I'm thinking, if there's a way to do something like this, but I think this is not possible in C#:

```
public class OnSetPropertyListener<DllClass>
{
    public void OnSetProperty(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, DllClass instance) 
    {
        // set another value, for example: "new value"
    }
}
```

How can I override the value set in DllClassProperty? Is it possible?

Comment: Can you modify the `DllClass` class itself to consult web.config if the value isn't otherwise set?

Comment: "and I need to override the value" do you mean that you need to **overwrite** the value? so "if a parammeter is seted on Web.config." you want to give the `DllClassProperty` in all "thousand of instances" a new value? did I get you right?

Comment: @JonSkeet No. It's a closed dll

Comment: Right - I suggest you add that to your question then. Are you able to replace everywhere that you create an instance with a call to a factory method instead (in your own code) that creates an instance and populates the property based on web.config?

Comment: @MongZhu No. I want to verify at the set momment if a parammeter is seted on Web.config, if it's seted, at run time, after executing dllInstance.DllClassProperty = "XPTO" I want to change "XPTO" with the value seted on Web.config

Comment: @JonSkeet Right, but with a factory I'll need to change a thousand of LoC. I don't want that

Comment: If you can't change the code in `DllClass` or the code that *uses* `DllClass`, you're out of options then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Surprisingly, there *is* a way to solve your problem. It's not pretty, but it satisfies the constraints of your question.

**Step 1**: Create a wrapper around `DllClass`, i.e. a new class `MyDllClassWrapper`, which behaves exactly like `DllClass` except for the change that you want to implement. This is usually done by rebuilding the public interface of `DllClass` and just forwarding all operations to a private `DllClass` instance.

Now you just need to use `MyDllClassWrapper` everywhere where you currently use `DllClass`. You mentioned in the comments that you don't want to change all those calls, so let's automate that:

**Step 2**: Use [Substitute.Fody](https://github.com/tom-englert/Substitute.Fody) to automatically replace all references to `DllClass` by references to `MyDllClassWrapper` in a post-compile step:

```
[assembly: Substitute(typeof(DllClass), typeof(MyDllClassWrapper))]
```

---

Note, though, that everyone reading your code will be *thoroughly confused*, since the source code points to `DllClass`, but `MyDllClassWrapper` is used instead. Thus, I recommend that you use this technique only as a *temporary workaround* until you find the time to cleanly replace all references to `DllClass` with references to `MyDllClassWrapper`.

Comment: Is it some what like an adapter design pattern approach?

Comment: @FaizanRabbani: I think the matching design pattern would be the [Decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

Comment: @Heinzi Outstanding! It's exactly what I need. I'll use it as a temporary workaround as you said. Actually, I'll use the wrapper just for development validation. This property is an e-mail property and I'll set my e-mail for validate all the e-mails sent by the project. Thanks a lot.