# Call function A when given function B is called

Tags: c#

Having two classes:

```
public class Foo {
    public void foo() {}
}

public class Bar {
    public void bar() {}
}
```

Where `Foo` is provided by an imported library can we run `bar()` when `foo()` is called? We cannot edit the `Foo` class and we want to do this in the least amount of code possible.

Comment: Do you have control over the instances of Foo? Can you inherit from it or at least create a wrapper for it?

Comment: AOP exists for this. Create a `FooWrapper` and call `FooWrapper._foo.foo()`

Comment: @GiladGreen yes, to both of the questions

Comment: How are instances of Foo & Bar related? Unless method _"bar"_ is static - how would you select the instance of Bar to be used.

Comment: If you don't want to change any line of code, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48461526/5071902 it's a very ugly workaround, but it works